# How to FULLY clear terminal screen?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I need to clear terminal fully, so the full terminal become darkfull.

What I mean by "fully", I need to `username@machine$:` not to pop up so terminal after clear would be completely empty. Just like `cmatrix` does before drawing digital rain.

Comment: You want to `username@machine$:` never show on screen ? Can you clarify your question a little ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy not never but the first time. You can look at `cmatrix` package, i need the same realization as they clear screen before drawing digital rain.

Comment: and have you tried the `reset` command ? `cmatrix`, however, uses `ncurses` library, so it doesn't just clear the screen. It opens completely different text interface.

Comment: @sudodus actually no, because I'll have to use that space.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Yes I did, but it still shows me `username@machine$:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command prompt format is stored in the `PS1` environment variable. If you set it to the empty string, no command prompt will be displayed. You can then `clear` the console:

```bsh
user@host:$ PS1=
clear
```

If you need to restore it afterwards, you can save the initial value in a different variable first:

```bsh
user@host:$ PS1_INITIAL=$PS1 # store the initial value
user@host:$ PS1=
PS1=$PS1_INITIAL # restore the initial value
user@host:$
```

Or you can `source` `.bashrc` where the original values are defined:

```bsh
. ~/.bashrc
user@host:$
```

Comment: That looks pretty much like an answer, but how can i exit that mode?

Comment: Allright, I've understood, if i want to exit that mode i have to save command prompt in another variable and restore it. Thanks.

Comment: Close the terminal. `PS1=` will only set the environment variable in that specific terminal. Or set it back to the default value which you can see by running `echo $PS1` in a different terminal (one that shows the default prompt).

Comment: @V.Dalechin It's not a mode. `PS1` prompt is the text shown before the cursor. You never entered a mode. After a command `clear` is issued you still can type in commands, but `PS1` is set to empty empty string. All you have to do is set `PS1` to something again.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @V.Dalechin, thanks for the comment. I added your suggestion to restore the initial value.